# A geometric property of a triangle involving its circumcircle and orthocentre.

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, orthogonality

Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle with orthocentre $H$ and circumcircle $Γ$. Let $BH$ intersect $AC$ at $E$, and let $CH$ intersect $AB$ at $F$. Let AH intersect $Γ$ again at $P$ which is  not equal to $A$. Let PE intersect $Γ$ again at $Q$ which is not equal to $P$. Prove that $BQ$ bisects segment $EF$.

This is an exam question which I gave yesterday. So there is no point for me trying it now... I want to see how it will be done..

Edit:
Let the reflection of $H$ over $AC$ be $X$. Clearly triangles $BFE$ and $PHX$ are similar.
Since $PE$ is a median in triangle $PHX$ it follows that $BQ$ is a median in triangle $BFE$.
Hence $BQ$ bisects $EF$.
This is what I have done... Am I correct?

Comment: A drawing is necessary for such kind of questions.

Comment: OK..... So I am doing so

Comment: I fear your conclusion is wrong... draw an arbitrary cyclic quadrilateral with geogebra